# Dúvida sobre inicialização de classe derivada em Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Imagine que eu tenha uma classe base `Food` e vou criar uma segunda classe `Rice` que vai herdar as funcionalidades da classe `Food`.

Se na hora de inicializar, qual a diferença se eu fizer:

```
class Rice(Food):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

ou fizer:

```
class Rice(Food):
    def __init__(self):
        Food.__init__(self)
```

Dá na mesma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu exemplo, não há diferença, é a mesma coisa. A diferença só aparece quando você usa herança múltipla em forma de diamante:

```
    A
  /   \
 B     C
  \   /
    D

class A:
    def teste(self):
        print("teste em A")

class B(A):
    def teste(self):
        print("teste em B")
        super().teste() # Equivalente a A.teste(self)

class C(A):
    def teste(self):
        print("teste em C")
        super().teste() # Equivalente a A.teste(self)

class D(B, C):
    def teste(self):
        print("teste em D")
        super().teste() # ?????????????????

d = D()
d.teste()
```

Como a classe `D` herda tanto de `B` quanto de `C`, dentro do método `D.teste` você teria que chamar **ambos os métodos** `C.teste(self)` e `B.teste(self)`, porém, como cada um desses chama `A.teste`, o resultado sem usar o `super()`seria que `A.teste` seria chamado **duas vezes**.

A solução é o `super()` - ele serve para que cada método ancestral seja chamado somente uma vez, em ordem de definição.

A saída será:

```
teste em D
teste em B
teste em C
teste em A
```

Answer (score 0):

O super() é utilizado entre heranças de classes, ele nos proporciona extender/subscrever métodos de uma super classe (classe pai) para uma sub classe (classe filha), através dele definimos um novo comportamento para um determinado método construído na classe pai e herdado pela classe filha.

Para entender melhor, considere o código abaixo como exemplo:

## Python 2

```
class Pai(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print('Construindo a classe Pai')

class Filha(Pai):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Filha, self).__init__()
```

## Python 3

```
class Pai(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print('Construindo a classe Pai')

class Filha(Pai):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

Comment: Obrigado! Compreendi o intuito de usarmos o `super()`, mas o que eu gostaria mesmo de saber é a diferença entre as duas formas de usar que mencionei na pergunta.

Comment: A resposta, apesar de correta e conter informações sobre o `super()`, não corresponde à pergunta que foi feita.